# Bind SQL query to actual objects (Algebrizer) ,does relational engine need Storage engine's involvement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, sql-server-2012

**Background**

I have been reading MS SQL Server query processing internals and almost all of them explains,  only during execution phase (post parsing & optimization) the relational engine talks to storage engine for data access.

But [Algebrizer](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/), to bind the SQL Text with actual objects, would certainly need system catalog, which I believe lies within [Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx) Database.

**Questions**

1. In that case , would the relational engine **not** need Storage engine's help  during **parsing phase** itself (ahead of execution phase)?!
2. If yes, then is it like, for every query execution, there would be 2 phase of disk/buffer pool reads?

   - to Parse (then optimize) and
   - to Execute?

**PS:**
I don't think so but please help to clarify this confusion

Cant attach/link query Processing Picture (don't have enough points to link).

Comment: The resource database shouldn't be needed for the schemas of a normal user database. That information is stored within the individual database. I imagine that schema information is cached within server data structures, so there shouldn't need to be additional disk reads, but obviously at some point that information will be need to be read in.